# How to prevent gym gloves stench?

Tags: gym, exercise-equipment, gloves

After using my gloves for a while, they begin to stink. I don't try to launder them too much as it's wrecking them. I have had those for 2 years already, and they're still usable. I don't want to waste them by throwing them away. It's not an option to replace, as I'm trying to save as much as I can.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bah! Use this as an excuse to wean yourself off of gloves. Lift raw and strengthen your grip for free.

Comment: i agree with Greg if your a guy but i need my ladies to have soft hands if you get my drift ;)

Comment: I'm a guy but I don't like callus and blisters. Hence the gloves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a zip lock bag and 4 tablespoons of baking soda. Put gloves into bag after workout and shake it like a paint mixer.

Well bacteria thrives off of your sweat so baking soda will absorb the moisture and stop the stink.

Oh and i forgot but another way is to throw your gloves into the **freezer** it will kill the bacteria that causes the stink.

Comment: Brilliant!!! That slipped my mind, as I am using baking soda as deodorant! I'm a big believer of baking soda. Good idea and thanks! I'm sure it will work!

Answer (score 2):

I leave mine in the sun (on my dash) afterwards.  They get a little faded, but they never stink.

Comment: Hi @Real John Conner, would you also happen to know how that keeps the smell off?

Comment: Sunlight kills bacteria.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a dryer sheet in each glove will help them dry faster and stink less. I use them in my vibrams too.